# Best web editable grid with export to excel functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, jquery-plugins

I am looking for an editable web grid table (javascript?) where you can:

1. Check a check box at the end of certain data rows indicating those rows will be updated.
2. Can export data into excel spreadsheet
3. Nice looking

Thanks so much for your help!

Regards,
Nign